# how to reference to a image file in <img src/> using RazorEngine for generating HTML Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, html-email, razorengine

I am using the RazorEngine library to generate HTML email.In the HTML email, I would like to include an image of my client's logo. However, I have problem showing it. I have my html template defined in a .cshtml file. The logo image is place in "~/Images/Logo.png". I have verified that the image file is copied to the server, with the Copy to Output Directory set to Copy Always.

So my question is how should I define the expression for the src attribute in my .cshtml?

```
<img src="@????"/>
```

**EDIT (My Solution)**: ok I thought there is a straight forward way to retrieve from the TemplateBase. I guess not. So I just grab the root site url using the GetSiteRootUrl() method and prepend it to my Image's url and then set it as a property in my Model's class.

inside the model class

```
LogoImageUrl = GetSiteRootUrl() + "Images/logo.png";
```

the .cshtml definition

```
<img src="@Model.LogoImageUrl" />
```

method that gets the site's root url

```
public static string GetSiteRootUrl()
    {
        var appPath = string.Empty;

        //Getting the current context of HTTP request
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        //Checking the current context content
        if (context != null)
        {
            //Formatting the fully qualified website url/name
            appPath = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",
                                    context.Request.Url.Scheme,
                                    context.Request.Url.Host,
                                    context.Request.Url.Port == 80
                                        ? string.Empty
                                        : ":" + context.Request.Url.Port
                                    );
        }

        if (!appPath.EndsWith("/"))
            appPath += "/";

        return appPath;
    }
```

Comment: Just put in a URL on a live web server.

Answer (score 3):

`"~"` typically means *"use the root url of this web request"* and since an email is not attached to a web request there is no way to resolve that. Instead, use the full url to your server. If you use this in more than one file I would recommend placing it into an appSetting in your web.config file so you can change it without having to find-replace a bunch of files.

Comment: having similar problem, when I browse from browser `https://localhost:56180/images/T102231.png` getting an image, but when `<img src="https://localhost:56180/images/T102231.png" />` not loading. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Server.MapPath` or `Url.Content` for that:

```
<img src="@Server.MapPath("~/Images/Logo.png")"/>
```

Or

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Logo.png")"/>
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if they are indeed running RazorEngine from a web environment. Probably a safe bet since the OP used the asp.net tag but it's possible that they are not or that the request comes from a url that is not publicly accessible (I'm not sure but I believe if you did the request from the local machine using `http://localhost/...` that would also be the generated url.)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Thanks for pointing that out. I supposed OP thought of that because else all `Url` and several other elements wouldn't work.